# Request JSON Data from HTTPS with C++?

Tags: c++, json, https, boost-asio, wxwidgets

I'm writing a program in C++ that needs to download JSON data from an HTTPS URL. The program is based on wxWidgets. That URL is for the translation service at [Glosbe](https://en.glosbe.com/a-api)

So I've tried multiple different libraries including:

- libcurl
- Boost.Asio
- the http functionality included in wxWidgets
- wxCurl
- Urdl

However, it always throws an error saying it can't connect, or I get a reply that says "Moved Permanently".

When i copy and paste the URL I am testing it with into a browser, it returns the JSON data perfectly.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**301 Moved Permanently** is what the server responds when you try to access the page with HTTP instead of HTTPS. Here's a complete response I just received from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 20:25:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://en.glosbe.com/a-api
```

It means exactly that: ***"The content you are looking for is really at https://en.glosbe.com/a-api."*** Your browser simply adheres to the HTTP protocol by following the server's hint and automatically proceeding to request `https://en.glosbe.com/a-api` when you try to access `http://en.glosbe.com/a-api`. It works seamlessly for you as a user.

You will have to read more documentation to create HTTPS requests yourself. Each of the libraries you mentioned will have a different way of supporting HTTPS (or not support it at all). For example, have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html, especially the "Notes" section where it says that *"OpenSSL is required to make use of Boost.Asio's SSL support."*

Comment: I'll test it out with boost.asio and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Seriously I won't recommend writing a HTTP client with Boost Asio to an OP that couldn't interpret a HTTP 301 response. Instead, use e.g. libcurl that knows how to do it all (including following redirects, proxies and SSL)

Comment: @sehe: I did not intend to recommend that. In fact, my point was just that this is going to be a bit complicated and that he must read the documentation of whatever library he uses.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Ok. I admit that I can read the answer as such :) Anyways, happy to have the comments clarify :0